# MediaWiki Main_Page short URL in domain root without redirect

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, mediawiki

What would be the rewrite rules looks like when making mediawiki URL from http://wiki.domain.com/Main_Page to http://wiki.domain.com only?

Comment: http://laxstrom.name/blag/2015/08/31/mediawiki-short-urls-with-nginx-and-main-page-without-redirect/ provides the solution for MediaWiki 1.26alpha.

Comment: Hi, did you manage to achieve the result that you wanted? If so, how did you do it?